# Using recursion to find non-infinite and infinite nestings of objects

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, recursion, ecmascript-6

I have a bunch of techniques (as in fighting moves) from which I'm looking to find all sequences. Each object has a property called 'results' which contains what can be done after this technique. It is possible, that a result contains another technique, which contains multiple results itself which may or may not contain another technique, and so on.

So the situation is very similar to my other [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73598469/traversing-an-entire-object-with-a-nested-property-recursively)

However, my use case is a little different from the one in the previous question:

- I need to find all sequences (non-closed loops) and all cycles (closed loops)
- I need the sequential and cyclic snapshots to be found, instead of the techniques

I adjusted the first answer to return snapshots and removed the random stop-condition while still using recusion, it now looks like this:

```
public createSequences(): void {
    function findAllPaths(initialTechniques: Technique[]): SequenceData[] {
      const result: SequenceData[] = [];
      function handle(snapshot: Snapshot, currentPath: Snapshot[] = []): void {
        currentPath = [...currentPath, snapshot];
        const continuations = snapshot.technique?.results.filter(
          (v) => v?.technique
        );
        if (continuations?.length) {
          continuations.forEach((t) => {
            if (!currentPath.map((r) => r.id).some((id) => id == t.id)) {
              // not in the current array-path
              handle(t, currentPath);
            }
            // else alredy in the array --> Discard
          });
        } else if (snapshot.technique) {
          result.push({ sequentialSnapshots: currentPath });
        }
      }
      initialTechniques.forEach((t) => t.results.forEach((r) => handle(r)));
      return result;
    }

    this.sequences.push(...findAllPaths(this.data));
  }
```

However my sequence function is missing two expected values and I cannot really figure out why:

Elbow-Strike -> Backflip

Elbow-Strike -> Butterfly-Kick -> Knee-Action

Here's a [stacklitz of my attempt](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-n2mpvc?file=src/app/app.component.ts). There you can uncomment lines 132 - 139 to add a snapshot that closes a cycle. Remove these lines again so there are no closed cycles.

Comment: The question should have all information that is needed to understand the question embedded into it, not behind links.

Comment: Finding if something is infinite is basically the Halting problem — it's impossible to solve.

Comment: Just updated the question to include more information. The sequences will be reasonably deep so iterating through them is possible and whenever we find the  snapshot which contains first technique of the cycle again, we know the cycle will be infinite

Answer (score 0):

Your Sequences and Cylcles need to store `Technique[]` because the `.name` property exists on `Technique`.

But your change from `Technique[]` to `Snapshot[]` means we cannot see the beginning of a sequence because a `Snapshot` only holds a reference to its descendant `Technique` in a sequence, not its *parent* `Technique`.

In your output, you see -

```
Knee-Action

Backflip

Butterfly-Kick -> Knee-Action
```

You are seeing the correct snapshots, but each snapshot only displays its descendants. The *{{parent}}* techniques are not -

```
{{Butterfly-Kick -> }} Knee-Action

{{Elbow Strike -> }} Backflip

{{Elbow Strike -> }} Butterfly-Kick -> Knee-Action
```

A possible solution might involve defining `SequenceData` and `CycleData` -

```
class SequenceData {
  techniques: Technique[];
  constructor(techniques: Technique[]) {
    Object.assign(this, { techniques });
  }
}

class CycleData {
  techniques: Technique[];
  constructor(techniques: Technique[]) {
    Object.assign(this, { techniques });
  }
}
```

Edit the `graph` function found in [your previous Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73600302/633183) to support cycle detection -

```
function* graph(
  t,
  path = [],
  seen = new Set()
): Generator<SequenceData | CycleData> {
  
  // cycle check
  if (seen.has(t)) return yield new CycleData([...path, t]); // <- CycleData
  
  // mark current node as seen
  seen.add(t);

  // traverse t
  switch (t?.constructor) {
    case Snapshot:
      if (t.technique) yield* graph(t.technique, path, seen);
      break;
    case Technique:
      for (const snapshot of t.results)
        yield* graph(snapshot, [...path, t], seen);
      yield new SequenceData([...path, t]); // <- SequenceData
      break;
    default:
      throw Error(`unsupported type: ${t?.constructor}`);
  }
}
```

Another solution could be to use a single type and set a `type` property -

```
enum MoveDataType { Sequence, Cycle }

class MoveData {
  type: MoveDataType;
  techniques: Technique[];
  constructor(type: MoveDataType, techniques: Technique[]) {
    Object.assign(this, { type, techniques });
  }
}
```

Then you can update *graph* to `graph(Snapshot | Technique): Generator<MoveData>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! It really helped a lot. I need an array of snapshots on the sequence/cycle data though, because there is other relevant information in there, besides the technique. It is also not enough for the first and last technique to be equal, the first and last snapshots need to be equal.

Comment: Regarding the missing information on the first technique: each technique has a property named 'entries' which is also of type snapshot[].The snapshots in this array contain each possible way to get to the technique. So if T1 has a result with T1, T2 will have an entry containing T1. We could use these to detect sequences/cycles and have snapshots in our array instead of techniques